# react-native project failing in xcode no matter what branch?

Tags: xcode, react-native

- I have a staging branch which builds successfully.
- I create a branch "zendesk" and then I add
  `react-native-zendesk-support` and `react-native link` it
- Build fails.
- Ok no problem, I close everything out (xcode and so forth) and switch back to staging branch.

  - Build fails and I see react-native-zendesk-support in my Libraries still.

I havne't touched the gitignore since react-native init... is the above expected behavior? Seems like a pretty poor default setup.

Comment: When switching between branches, you must clean the project before running it again. Product > Clean.

Comment: Great tip I didn't realize that. Unfortunately react-native-zendesk-support seems to have destroyed my ios folder regardless of the branch I'm on.